# Solution needed with a homework - C#

Tags: c#

I am learning C# atm and trying to solve one of the problems discribed in my book.
Write a program that calculate and prints (accuracy of 0.001) the sequence 1 + 1/2 - 1/3 + 1/4 - 1/5 + .... I know that this is a common problem, but yet I lost almost a whole day to solve it and yet I can't do it alone (maybe I am not trying hard enough).

```
static void Main()
{
    double sum = 0D;
    double sum1 = 0d;
    int i = 1;
    while ( i <100)
    {
        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum1 = sum1 +(1 / i);
        }
        else
        {
            sum1 = sum1 -(1 / i);
        }

        sum = sum1 + sum;
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(sum, 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: OK do you want the string sequence of 1 + 1/2 - 1/3, or 1 + 0.5 - 0.333...?

Comment: It's the harmonic series. Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since "i" is an integer, division 1/i will always result in 0 (except the case when i=1) as "/" is an integer division operator and it never gives fractions. So you should divide a double value 1.0/i to get fraction.

In addition the loop condition i<100 isn't what you need. It is better to set there (1.0/i > 0.001) or transformed (i<1000). For the sequence you have it will guarantee the required accuracy.

Comment: Oh, yes now i got it. Thats why i cant get any fraction !!!!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calculating it to an accuracy of 0.001, you are rounding it on each step. You need to let your loop run as long as `abs(current_sum - previous_sum) >= 0.001`. `current_sum` is the sum of the current iteration, and `previous_sum` the one of the previous iteration.

Answer (score -2):

You already know that this is the harmonic series?

[Wikipedia on harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29)

It is quite easy to calculate, but I am not sure what you mean with
the precission part.

```
        double harmonic = 0;
        int partialSumsUpTo = 10000;

        for (double i = 1; i <= partialSumsUpTo; ++i)
        {
            double part = 1 / i;
            harmonic += Math.Round(part, 5);
        }
```

**Please note** that this is no spoiler, as you want the **alternating harmonic series**
for your homework. But you will get that part for sure on your own.

Comment: -1: Note the OP alternates addition and subtraction.

Comment: why -1? I wrote that this is no spoiler because he wants alternating harmonic series! Have a look at my answer. Note that this is homework and a spoiler is considered a bad thing! made those two things bold, that everybody can see them more easily

Comment: @Richard Please reread the answer and consider your -1 again, as I already stated that this is no spoiler. I knew that addition and subtraction are alternating and clearly stated that in my answer!

Comment: If you don't want to help with homework too much then don't help. There are two issues in the Q: integer division and how to do the rounding this addresses neither. The alternation was just the way this A is clearly not answering the question (whatever the disclaimer).